# Set navbar current menu active

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using asp.net 4.0 with bootstrap3. I used navbar in my master page, and i tried this jquery code to make current menu active.
Below is the code

```html
$('.nav li a').click(function (e) {
          
            var $this = $(this);
            if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
          
        });
```

this works fine but when current menu page loads it is becoming inactive.
How to set active for current menu?

Comment: Are you saying when your page loads it is becoming inactive? Is your script loaded on the layout page. i.e. is the script common on all pages. When loading a current page does it open in a new page? Let me know if i am not making sense.

Comment: show us how you load your page?

Comment: @Vikash, have you tried suggestions given? If they didn't work please let us know so that people could improve their posts, if one of the answers helped you somehow put an upvote and if an answer solved your problem mark that post as the answer. This is how community acts here, on StackOverflow. By the way, you gain reputation when you "mark as answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way (more complex) is:

First of all, your master page's design (navbar):

```
<li id="liContacts" runat="server">
    <a href="Contact.aspx">Contacts</a>
</li>
```

Master page code behind:

```
public String linkContacts
{
    get 
    {
        return "not_active";
    }
    set
    {
        liContacts.Attributes.Add("class", "" + value + "");
    }
}
```

Add following code to your Content page's header:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %> <!-- change path to your master page //-->
```

Content page's code behind:

```
this.Master.linkContacts = "active";
```

Answer (score 0):

You set css class to an element and then reload the page, so, changes are lost there. One of the ways to accomplish what you're trying to do is to add this js code to your master page (customize selector for your case):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main-navbar .nav a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```